# Tailwind css not working with Handlebars file in Vite setup

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, tailwind-css, vite

I'm trying vite setup and have tailwindcss and handlebars (to add some partial html functionality).

The issue is intellisense is working correctly but whenever I am saving handlebars partial its updating textual and classes changes but classes are not applied from tailwind end, but when I resave index.html or main.js file from that same project everything seems working and the classes I added to partial also work in that way.

attaching my config files below to see if I am making some mistake in it.

**postcss.config.js**

```
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import tailwindConfig from "./tailwind.config.js";

export default {
  plugins: [tailwind(tailwindConfig), autoprefixer],
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
export default {
  prefix: "six-",

  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./test.html",
    "./*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./parts/*.html",
  ],
  purge: ["./index.html", "./test.html", "./*.js", "./parts/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import postcss from "./postcss.config.js";
import { resolve } from "path";
import handlebars from "vite-plugin-handlebars";

export default {
  plugins: [
    handlebars({
      partialDirectory: resolve(__dirname, "parts"),
      context: {
        title: "Hello, world!",
      },
    }),
  ],
  css: {
    postcss,
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "v1",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "vite": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "vite-plugin-handlebars": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body class="six-bg-teal-100">
    {{> header}}
    <div
      id="app"
      class=""
      delay="2000"
      img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1660675716662-7e7b19395d44?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
    ></div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**parts/header.html** (handlebars partial)

```
<div class="six-font-bold six-text-green-400 six-text-6xl">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Show us some HTML code where it does not work

Comment: @tauzN thanks for your comment, I've updated my question with index.html and header.html (handlebars file)

Answer (score 1):

Seems it’s an issue with the
vite-plugin-handlebars

PostCSS is not being called

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8784

Answer (score 0):

Don't import PostCSS plugins, just define them, and use the deafult tailwind config like this:

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

tailwind config should export a module

```js
//tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ 
module.exports = {
  prefix: "six-",
  content: ["./index.html", "./*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./parts/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time for this, unfortunately still the same issue with tailwind not updating in handlebars with vite hmr, btw I should have mentioned earlier that I do have index.css file with the tailwind content and that file was imported in my main.js , I've tried it your way though the result is same.

Comment: It's hard to help, when you omit critical code...

Answer (score 0):

Code below work for me even with default export, I have same problem.

I just add one more path for "Tailwind config file" where provide path to my partials files dir.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/partials/*.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```